# Angularjs $routeParams issue

Tags: angularjs

I am struggling to get $routeParams to work. What I want to do is populate  an unsubscribe field with an email address that is contained in a link to a url. I am using AngularJS and after reading around the subject is seemed $routeParam was the way to go but I cannot get it to work

My HTML:

```
        <form class="form-signin" name="regForm">
                 <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
       </form>
```

My .config with $routeProvider

```
    .config(['$routeProvider',  function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
     .when('/unsubscribe/:email', {
         templateUrl: 'unsubscribe/unsubscribe.html',
         controller: 'unsubscribeCtrl'
     })
 }]);
```

My .controller with $routeParams

```
.controller('unsubscribeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams) {

   var param1 = $routeParams.email

   console.log(param1)
 }]);
```

Now when I navigate to myURL/app/#/unsubscribe?email=some_text the browser remains blank and I do not get any errors in the console. Am I mis-understanding how $routeParams is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you are trying to access doesn't match the given route in `$routeparams` table. You should try to navigate `app/#/unsubscribe/some_text`.
The `$routeparams` will understand that email is some_text

Comment: Thanks, I was close but put in the wrong piece of the jigsaw at the end!

Comment: You are just 0.02 later than me, and you answer got accept, nice :) +1

Answer (score 0):

As your URL is configured in router, your URL in browser should be below, then only you can get `email` value as `some_text` from `$routeParams`

```
myURL/app/#/unsubscribe/some_text
```

Answer (score 0):

`$routeParams` is populated by the named parameters embedded in the path (e.g., in `/unsubscribe/:email`, `:email` is the parameter that will be extracted).

On top of that, the router tries to match the path portion of the url (without the `?…`) to the list of known routes, which in this case only includes `/unsubscribe/:email`.

So, to make the email parameter available to the controller in `$routeParams`, you should point your browser at `myURL/app/#/unsubscribe/some_text` instead.